# Two processes mmap same file on linux, when is the memory shared?

Tags: linux, file, ipc, shared-memory, mmap

Under what circumstances is the physical memory backing mmap of the same file shared between processes in linux?

I understand, that the necessary condition is `MAP_SHARED`.
I understand, that if the processes use same file descriptor (e.g., child inheriting it from parent), the memory will be shared.

But what happens if, e.g.,

- each process opens the file on its own?
- one opens it for read and the other for write?
- one process `mmap`s the file with `PROT_READ` and other with `PROT_WRITE`?

Comment: From The Linux Programming Interface. "All processes mapping the same region of a file [with `MAP_SHARED`] share the same physical pages of memory, which are initialized from a file region. Modifications to the contents of the mapping are carried through to the file." It means it doesn't matter how the file was opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this part of the Linux man page for `mmap()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html#:%7E:text=MAP_SHARED%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Share%20this,msync(2).):

> MAP_SHARED
> Share this mapping.  Updates to the mapping are visible to               other processes mapping the same region, and (in the case               of file-backed mappings) are carried through to the               underlying file.

To answer your specific questions:

1. It doesn't matter whether the processes are forked and using the same file descriptor, or independently opened the same file (even via different path names). All the matters is they've mapped the same file, as determined by inode on the filesystem, and then invoked `mmap(MAP_SHARED)`.
2. The `O_RDWR` mode of the file descriptor controls whether it's permitted for that process to pass `PROT_WRITE`, otherwise the `mmap()` call from that process will fail with `EACCESS`, (from the [same man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html#:%7E:text=EACCES%20A%20file,is%20append%2Donly.)):

> Errors:
> EACCES
> file  mapping was requested, but fd is not open for reading.
> MAP_SHARED was requested and PROT_WRITE is set, but fd is               not open in read/write (O_RDWR) mode. Or PROT_WRITE is               set, but the file is append-only.

3. The `PROT_READ`/`PROT_WRITE` flags control the readability/writeability of the virtual page table entries created in the corresponding process who made the `mmap()` call (and hence that process's ability to read and write). This has no effect on other processes mapping the same file pages (who might differ in read/write access based on the flags to their own `mmap` call).

Authoritative pages with additional information and some useful examples:

1. [IBM's mmap documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/mmap.html)
2. [GNU libc documentation for mmap](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html)
3. [linuxhint.com blog article](https://linuxhint.com/using_mmap_function_linux/)

Comment: I read the man page of course. From the language itself it is not 100% clear to me that the two processes would share a physical memory page. To give a counter example, on MacOS and BSD they wouldn't and the propagation would be achieved through aliased memory (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74600379/difference-between-aliased-ali-and-shared-shm-memory-on-macos)

Comment: @SamuelHapak see the second ref just added above: "MAP_SHARED
This specifies that writes to the region will be written back to the file. Changes made will be shared immediately with other processes mmaping the same file."

Comment: The second reference seems promising. I am not a Linux expert, so forgive me my dumb question, but wouldn't there be other ways to make changes immediately available to other process (e.g. copying the memory regions?). As I wrote earlier, MacOS does "aliased memory" in this instance, which is significantly worse than shared physical memory, but still gets the job done. AFAIK there is nothing such as aliased memory in Linux, which makes me believe you are probably right here.

Comment: @SamuelHapak in case you're still doubting, here's a [pointer to our use of this technique in the shared-memory support for our portable production library](https://bitbucket.org/berkeleylab/gasnet/src/5971da017b41578c6e49b751ea640e06de23c59a/gasnet_mmap.c#lines-619:648). The lines marked with `GASNETI_PSHM_FILE` are relevant to the technique in this question, whereas the similar (mutually exclusive) `GASNETI_PSHM_POSIX` compilation mode uses `shm_open()` to `mmap` shared memory that won't incur file system traffic. See https://gasnet.lbl.gov/ for details on where this library runs.